# RejectedExecutionException inside single executor service

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice

In one of our services, someone added such (simplified) a piece of code:

```
public class DeleteMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DeleteMe d = new DeleteMe();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; ++i) {
            d.trigger(i);
        }
    }

    private Future<?> trigger(int i) {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<?> f = es.submit(() -> {
            try {
                // some long running task
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return f;
    }
}
```

This fails *sometimes* with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3148f668 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6e005dc9[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:678)
    at com.erabii.so.DeleteMe.trigger(DeleteMe.java:29)
    at com.erabii.so.DeleteMe.main(DeleteMe.java:22)
```

Most of the time the error is `OutOfMemoryError` - which I perfectly understand. The person writing the code never invoked `ExecutorService::shutDown`, thus keeping it alive too much. Of course creating a separate executor service for each method call is bad and will be changed; but this is exactly why the error is seen.

The point that I do not understand is why `RejectedExecutionException` would be thrown, specifically it is being thrown [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1368).

Code comments [there](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1352) make some sense:

> 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or **saturated** and so reject the task.

If this is indeed the case, how come the documentation of `execute` does not mention this?

> If the task cannot be submitted for execution, either because this executor has been shutdown or because its capacity has been reached, the task is handled by the current RejectedExecutionHandler.

To be frank initially I though that `ExecutorService` is GC-ed - reachability and scope are different things and GC is allowed to clear anything which is *not* reachable; but there is a `Future<?>` that will keep a strong reference to that service, so I excluded this.

Comment: "but there is a `Future<?>` that will keep a strong reference to that service" - The `Future` is just returned by the method, but isn't being used/stored anywhere else. Maybe the JVM sees this and determines that it's unreachable?

Comment: @JacobG. as said - this is _simplified_.  _it is_ used in the callers, of course.

Comment: @JacobG. also notice `pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0` - this means _nothing_ has been submitted to the queue yet, which happens in the main thread. So the main thread (not the one from the pool), has to place the task in the queue and _then_ let go the execution to a _different_ thread - this did not even happen here.

Comment: Do you experience the same behavior if you use `newFixedThreadPool(1)` instead of `newSingleThreadExecutor()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrote

> To be frank initially I though that `ExecutorService` is GC-ed - reachability and scope are different things and GC is allowed to clear anything which is *not* reachable; but there is a `Future<?>` that will keep a strong reference to that service, so I excluded this.

But this is actually a very plausible scenario, which is described in [JDK-8145304](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304). In the bug report's example the `ExecutorService` is not held in a local variable, but a local variable does not prevent garbage collection per se.

Note that the exception message

```
Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3148f668 rejected from  
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6e005dc9[Terminated,
        pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

supports this, as the state of `ThreadPoolExecutor@6e005dc9` is specified as `Terminated`.

The assumption that futures hold a reference to their creating `ExecutorService` is wrong. The actual type depends on the service implementation, but for the common ones, it will be an instance of [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) which has no reference to an `ExecutorService`. It's also visible in the exception message that this applies to your case.

Even if it had a reference, the creator would be the actual `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but it is the wrapping `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` instance which gets garbage collected and calls `shutdown()` on the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance (Thin wrappers are generally good candidates for premature garbage collection in optimized code which just bypasses the wrapping).

Note that while the bug report is still open, the problem is actually fixed in JDK 11. There, the base class of `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`, the class `DelegatedExecutorService` has an `execute` implementation that looks like this:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    try {
        e.execute(command);
    } finally { reachabilityFence(this); }
}
```

Comment: me and my colleague came to almost the same conclusion before posting the question, but providing all these details would have been bad. thank you very much for confirming this!