# Why are local variables in the method being garbage collected in advance?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, executorservice, stack-frame

This is a multi-threaded test code, each time a newSingleThreadExecutor is created, and two other threads are constantly triggering gc. Under HotSpot java8 (1.8.0_221), there will be an error that the thread pool has been closed.

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ThreadPoolTest threadPoolTest = new ThreadPoolTest();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        Future<String> future = threadPoolTest.submit();
                        try {
                            String s = future.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Error e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


    public Future<String> submit() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                return System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
            }
        });
        executorService.execute(futureTask);
        return futureTask;
    }

}
```

After running for a while, you will get an error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@a5acd19 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@30890a38[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
at ThreadPoolTest.submit(ThreadPoolTest.java:54)
at ThreadPoolTest$1.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:12)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor creates an auto-closed thread pool (java.util.concurrent.Executors.FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService), so it should only be executed shutdown before the object is collect.

But from the error log, the executorService was shutdown in advance. Like before the stack frame popped, the finalized method of the executorService was executed ahead of time.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You never shut down each executor when it's done, so my guess is that you're just accumulating more and more active threads (each idle, but still there), until the JVM can't create new ones for new Executors.

Comment: But from the error log, it is caused by the thread pool shutdown, but the shutdown will only be performed under the java.util.concurrent.Executors.FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService#finalize function.

Comment: I'm saying it could be that it didn't shut down per se, but rather failed to properly start up in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, have found the problem, this is a bug in jdk. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304 ------            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714980/rejectedexecutionexception-inside-single-executor-service